# Flask with python 3.5

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, flask

I'm trying to run a flask app on my aws ec2 instance. I've installed anaconda with python 3.5.

In order to install mod-wsgi I run the following command:

```
sudo yum install libapache2-mod-wsgi python-pip git
```

The result was that a lot of python 2.6 dependencies got installed. I find this confusing as the python version that I'm running is supposed to be 3.5.

```
Dependency Installed:
  python26.x86_64 0:2.6.9-2.84.amzn1
  python26-backports.x86_64 0:1.0-3.14.amzn1
  python26-backports-ssl_match_hostname.noarch 0:3.4.0.2-1.12.amzn1
  python26-libs.x86_64 0:2.6.9-2.84.amzn1
  python26-setuptools.noarch 0:12.2-1.30.amzn1
```

You can see the output on this screenshot:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ4Nh.jpg)
Can you please clarify if there's something I need to do to install it for my python 3.5 (anaconda distribution) or why this is referring to python 2.6?

I'm using the following version of linux:

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2016.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2016.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2016.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2016.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
Amazon Linux AMI release 2016.03
```

thanks

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if this has anything to do with what you're experiencing, but you should avoid using Amazon Linux at all costs. If you want a RHEL-based distro, use CentOS. You'll have a much better experience in the short *and* long term.

Comment: Interesting, why do you suggest to avoid that distro? Do you have any links where I can read more about the differences of the different distributions? I'm a total beginner in this. thanks

Comment: The problems with Amazon Linux would certainly exceed the length of this comment box. I've not bothered to write them all down; maybe I should do that somewhere. The big three problems in brief: It's actually incompatible with RHEL/CentOS, often unstable and broken, and you're locked in to Amazon's cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You may have multiple versions of python installed.

> The result was that a lot of python 2.6 dependencies got installed. I
>   find this confusing as the python version that I'm running is supposed
>   to be 3.5.

Is your ec2 instance running 2.x or 3.x as the default python bin?

When you run at the command line "python" it should return output such as the below:

> $ python
>   Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27)
>   [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>   .>>>

If you want to set the default to 3.x, follow the answers here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256127/two-versions-of-python-on-linux-how-to-make-2-7-the-default

Comment: I installed anaconda and now when I start Python it says version 3.5. But I assume the original aws server had Python 2 installed.